# How to get UIwebView's JSContext in ios5?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, uiwebview, javascriptcore

As we know,Apple provide the javascriptcore.framework to work with javascript, and we can get the jscontext of uiwebview like this:
JSContext *context = [_webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
then we can invoke Script using context or implementating JSExport methods.
Now,my project must be compatible with ios5, but I want to invoke ios-object in javascript directly, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not allowed to link JavaScriptCore.framework when deployment target is lower than 7.0, you can't support iOS 5.